# Conjecture:$ \forall x , \exists m,n$, $ x<m<n $ and make $\pi(p_{m}+m) - m > \pi(p_{n}+n) - n$

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers

$p_i$ is the $i^{\rm th}$ prime. $\pi(x)$ is prime counting function.

Firstly, I think that Prime gap inequality holds true for any $i>0$: 
$p_{i+1} - p_{i} \leq i$.

Very often, $\pi(p_{m}+m) - m \leq \pi(p_{n}+n) - n$ if $m<n$ .
However, there exist counter examples. $\pi(17+7)-7 > \pi(19+8)-8$ .
I conjecture there exists infinite this sort of counter examples. In math words,

Conjecture:$ \forall x , \exists m,n$, satisfy $ x<m<n $ and $\pi(p_{m}+m) - m > \pi(p_{n}+n) - n$.

Comment: I have editing the typesetting a bit. Most significantly, I have replaced the $p[i]$ notation with the more standard subscript notation $p_i$. I haven't changed the wording otherwise. Hope this is ok. (My edit will be visible to all only after it is peer-reviewed.)

Comment: very kind of you!

Comment: How much and what kind of evidence do you have supporting your conjecture? Did you run some computer experiments (this should be rather easy to do)?

Comment: @Theo p = Prime;
pi = PrimePi; Table[pi[p[n] + n] - n, {n, 400, 500}]

Comment: This [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71639/) (by the same poster, I presume) seems related, but NOT a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have Mathematica, so I can't use your code (well - I could achieve that easily with sage, too, of course, if I wanted to). However, I was intending to suggest something that doesn't take a few microseconds only but would be a *serious* test. I mean, $\sim 35'000$ isn't very big.

Comment: @Srivatsan, Good eye! Yes, I posted a related question on MO.

Comment: t = Table[pi[p[n] + n] - n, {n, 100000, 101000}];
ListPlot[{t}]

Comment: What is the question?